# How to read from NativeReturnValue returned by NativeFunction in Frida?

Tags: frida

```js
// test.ts
Java.perform(function() {

    var malloc = new NativeFunction(
        Module.findExportByName('libc.so', 'malloc'),
        'pointer', // ret type
        ['uint32'] // arg type
    );

    var p = malloc(4);

    p.readU8(); // error
});
```

I'm trying to compile the above **.ts** file to **.js** with *frida-compile*. I tried to read from the variable p with `.readU8()` but error occurs: *Property 'readU8' does not exist on type 'NativeReturnValue'*

From the source code it's defined as:

```
type NativeReturnValue = NativePointer | UInt64 | Int64 | number | boolean | any[];
```

I know little about TypeScript, seems `NativeReturnValue` is some kind of `NativePointer`, but how to cast ?

Thanks.

Comment: From my understanding if you specify `pointer`as the returnType then the returned value is not a `NativePointer` but just a number so you have to wrap it `new NativePointer(p)` or short `ptr(p)`. Then you can call `.readU8()`.

Comment: @Robert Tried `new NativePointer(p).readU8()` and `ptr(p).readU8()`, but still error.

Comment: If the return value `p` is not `0` you could try `Memory.readU8(p);`

Comment: @Robert, this is in *.ts* file, it uses `frida-gum`, there is no `Memory.readU8()`

Comment: Why not using Frida directly? May be your problem is simply frida-gum.

Comment: @Robert frida doesn't support *import * other js file, I'm writing a library, which can be used by all other projects, this can only be done in *.ts*, which uses frida-gum.